# Color cells if same value found in a specified column

Tags: excel, vba

The following VBA code colors the cells in column B if the same value appears within column D.

I would like to also color column C. Changing the range to "B:D" does not work.

```
Sub HighlightCellIfValueExistsinAnotherColumn()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim Find As Variant
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet5")
    For x = 1 To ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Find = ws.Range("D:D").Find(What:=ws.Range("B" & x).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not Find Is Nothing Then
            If ws.Cells(Find.Row, 6).Value = 0 And ws.Cells(Find.Row, 9).Value = 0 Then
                ws.Range("B" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just use actual conditional formatting, instead of VBA?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, that could certainly work as well with some kind of vlookup formula. I thought however this would still be a reasonably simple example to try out some vba :)

Comment: `ws.Range("B" & x & ":C" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 6` maybe.

Comment: this did work, thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just duplicate the same command:

```
...
ws.Range("B" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
ws.Range("C" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
...
```

Add the D column if you wish.

EDIT:

I made adjustments to your code and annotate them to explain what the code means.
I used ListObjects/Table since that is what you have given as an example.  In my testing, the code highlighted A-C columns on rows 2 and 5 only.

```
Sub HighlightCellIfValueExistsinAnotherColumn()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim nRow, sourceCol, findCol As Long
    Dim FoundCell As Variant
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim LookupValue As String
        
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'Note: set a table name for your entire table range
    'I assumed "Table1" as its name so it is arbitrary
    Set lo = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    'column to iterate
    sourceCol = lo.ListColumns("List2").Index
    'column to search
    findCol = lo.ListColumns("Animals").Index
    
    'for each row of the list object
    For nRow = 1 To lo.ListRows.Count
        'what value to search
        LookupValue = lo.DataBodyRange.Cells(nRow, sourceCol)
        'try to find the value and return the cell
        Set FoundCell = lo.DataBodyRange.Columns(findCol).Find(LookupValue, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        
        'if value is found
        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            'check colums 6 and 9 if zero
            If ws.Cells(FoundCell.Row, 6).Value = 0 And ws.Cells(FoundCell.Row, 9).Value = 0 Then
                'color em yellow "List1", "List2" & "List3" for the current row
                lo.DataBodyRange.Cells(nRow, sourceCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                lo.DataBodyRange.Cells(nRow, sourceCol + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                lo.DataBodyRange.Cells(nRow, sourceCol - 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        End If
    Next nRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I think the problem here is that if a value is found in column A, it automatically colors B and C even if the value is not found in these columns (only in column A). And the plan in the end is to have a whole spreadsheet of values in a table, and all values should be colored if it appears both in the table and the specified column; so would become a bit too many lines to add in the end. Maybe also this a wrong approach to do this kind of task.

Comment: @Kingleoric sample data would have made your explanation much clearer. You made no mention of Column A in your original question. If you were on our shoe, what data do you think we will have in our mind? Just expressing our side...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, and of course your right. I created a sample file, i added a picture to my comment. Indeed, the aim is to make all cells in columns A-C colored, if they contain one of the values listed in column D. I hope this makes it clearer, and sorry for not doing this straight from the start.

Comment: In ws.Cells(Find.Row, 6).Value = 0 And ws.Cells(Find.Row, 9).Value = 0, why do you need to test if columns 6 and 9 are 0? Are there data in F and I columns?

Comment: yes, there will in the end even more columns. but i just put a larger number than the columns i had - as without this parameter it did not work. but i will get back to u as soon as i tried out your corrections. thank you already now tho :)